# Expect for loop does not work

Tags: for-loop, sh, expect

I can not figure it out how expect for loop works.

I have my code:

```
j=0
/usr/bin/expect << SSHLOGIN
..........
    for {set $j 0} {$j < 5} {incr $j 1} {
        expect {
        "*> " {
        send "$j\r"
        sleep 1
            }
            }
        }
...........
SSHLOGIN
```

And it gets an error like:

```
extra characters after close-brace
    while executing
"for {set j 0}{ < 5}{incr  1} {
"
```

If I declare j outside. Loop just gets stuck to 0 and repeats. I can not find any info about for loop inside expect. Has anyone tried that?

UPDATE: Declared variable outside, now it loops infinite times on 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is an extension to the Tcl language. Tcl syntax is very whitespace sensitive. You are not providing spaces between the arguments to the `for` command

```
for {set j 0} {$j < 5} {incr j} {
#............^........^
```

Note that the [`incr` command](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/incr.htm) expects a variable *name*, not a value.

Spend some time with the [`Tcl` man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) to learn about how Tcl works -- it will be well worth your time.

Also, I notice from the error message in your question that `$j` disappeared. Are you invoking expect from a shell script like this?

```
expect -c " ... your expect program here ..."
```

If you are, be aware that you have to protect expect's variables from being substituted by the shell before expect even starts. If possible, surround the expect program with single quotes.

---

Do this:

```
/usr/bin/expect << 'SSHLOGIN'
```

Quoting the here-doc terminator effectively quotes the entire heredoc. Otherwise the shell will substitute all the `$variables` as shell variables **before** handing the program to expect.

Some Tcl commands take a variable *name* not a value. `j` is a variable name. `$j` is a value. `set` and `incr` are two such commands. You must write

```
for {set  j 0} {$j < 5} {incr  j 1} {
# .......^....................^
#       no $                no $
```

Comment: I have updated a question with a way how I use expect. Spaces did not helped. But the webpage is really helpful I am trying few other ways how to do it, I will let you know.

Comment: This is a bit frustrating. I get the same results from 'expect -c".."' I have tried foreach, while and still no proper results...

Comment: Thanks it did the job... But then I want to add some variables from Shell script its a bit tricky. The idea that some commands use name helped me to trick the loop. Instead of closing expect part from $variables like 'SSHLOGIN'. I just wrote a loop like this: `for {set j 0} {[incr j 0] < 5} {incr j}`. `incr` uses a name and returns same value without going outside to Shell script to look for varaible.

Comment: You could also use `[set j]` which returns the value of j. I think very early versions of Tcl did not actually have the `$j` syntax since the functionality is provided by the set command.